# what is the best way to use Html.DropDownListFor when you have a list of objects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, html.dropdownlistfor

In my view model if have a:

```
  List<Car>
```

where car has an Id and a name.  I want to create a dropdown box using

```
Html.DropDownListFor()
```

what is the best way to hook this up as i want to have the value of the item be the Id and the display to be the Name of the Car.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's in your view model,

to display the list you want you would use

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("DropDownName", new SelectList(yourListOfCar, "Id", "Name"))%>
```

so if you want to use DropDownListFor, you would use is like this

```
<%= Html.DropDownList(model => model.IdCar, new SelectList(yourListOfCar, "Id", "UserName"))%>
```

where model is your view model